# ArrayList output repeating itself?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

So i've i'm trying to use a combobox to display different category options for different types of food. Each type of food has its own array list, so vegetables, fruits, dairy, etc. So when the user selects a food category, it will display all the foods from that category in a text area. However, the list keeps repeating itself an extra time whenever a different category is selected. So the first click is fine and will display the food list only once. But if you select a different category after that, the list will repeat itself. Here's the code i'm using right now:

```
public class foodTypesJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

// Food category arraylists
ArrayList <String> fruitsList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList <String> veggiesList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList <String> dairyList = new ArrayList();



public void foodCategory(String box, String category, ArrayList list)
{
    box = foodCategoryBox.getSelectedItem() + "";

    if (box.equals(category))
    {
        foodOutput.setText("");
        int indexNumber = 0; 
        // Display the different foods
        for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) 
        { 
            indexNumber = index + 1; 
            foodOutput.append(indexNumber + ". " + list.get(index) + "\n"); 
        }
    }
}        

private void categoryBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    String foodType = foodCategoryBox.getSelectedItem() + "";

    String fruits = "Fruits";
    String veggies = "Vegetables";
    String dairy = "Dairy";

    Collections.addAll(fruitsList, "Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry");
    Collections.addAll(veggiesList, "Lettuce", "Carrot", "Broccoli");
    Collections.addAll(dairyList, "Milk", "Cream", "Cheese");

    foodCategory(foodType, fruits, fruitsList);
    foodCategory(foodType, veggies, vegetableList);
    foodCategory(foodType, dairy, dairyList);
```

So with this, if i select the fruits category first, it will output 
" 1. Apple
  2. Orange
  3. Strawberry"
But if i select the veggies category after that, it will output
" 1. Lettuce
  2. Carrot
  3. Broccoli
  4. Lettuce 
  5. Carrot
  6 Broccoli"

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make it so the list will only display once?

Comment: Every time `categoryBoxActionPerformed` you add the items to the lists AGAIN, so the more times you call `categoryBoxActionPerformed`, the more times the lists will repeat

Comment: All you need to do is to re-initialize the `ArrayList` with every call of `categoryBoxActionPerformed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you invoke `categoryBoxActionPerformed`, you're adding the ***same*** items to the `ArrayLists`.

To solve this, you may do one of the following:

1. Either re-initialize the `ArrayLists` every time you invoke `categoryBoxActionPerformed()`, so it looks like this:

   ```
    //at the beginning of the method.
    fruitsList = new ArrayList<>();
    veggiesList = new ArrayList<>();
    dairyList = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. Or wrap it with a `boolean`:

   ```
    boolean firstTime = true; // create a global variable
   ```

Then wrap the addition:

```
    if(firstTime){
       Collections.addAll(fruitsList, "Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry");
       Collections.addAll(veggiesList, "Lettuce", "Carrot", "Broccoli");
       Collections.addAll(dairyList, "Milk", "Cream", "Cheese");
       firstTime = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You call  `Collections.addAll(...)` inside the `ActionEvent` listener this means the each click will add new elements into `ArrayList`. To fix that You need to initialize all lists in the constructor (which is more correctly in case You have fixed list of products) of your class or to call `clear()` method before `Collections.addAll(...)` for each list (in case if you really need to change lists of products inside the event listener)